# How to install the mrsid plugin for GDAL on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gdal

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://trac.osgeo.org/ubuntugis/wiki/TutorialMrSid) on installing the MrSID plugin on Ubuntu 20.04, but it isn't working. I downloaded the Lizardtech SDK for Ubuntu, untarred it, and get to step 2. This command `sudo apt-get install libgdal-mrsid-src` fails. I couldn't find any other tutorial and do not want to convert the MrSID file to any other format.

Does anyone know how to successfully install the plugin on Ubuntu? Thanks

Comment: I'm bumping into this as well. Did you manage to solve it @Ive ?